# What does it mean to initialize a string like "std::string mystring{""};". Is it new feature of C++ 11 or 14?

Tags: c++11, c++14

I am new to **C++ 11 & 14**. In my new role I saw a code where **string was initialized** (below) and I do not know what is this new way called and where to read about it. Can some one tell what is it called and how does it work. Regards.

```
std::string mystring{""};
```

Comment: I think this question shall not be removed. My reasoning is that if someone searches SO with keyword std::string {""} then they should get some results. In my case when I searched SO I got nothing. This question is going to be helpful for newbies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is initialization with string literal, refer to :https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string
see Notes.

Your example is same as std:string s{"",0};

Comment: Thanks v01d. Since it helped me to know _**what it is called in C++**_. I will mark your answer as accepted.

Comment: @Ahmed thank you, I appreciate it